# Android SignalR working without signalRFuture.get()

Tags: android, signalr

I am using SignalR library in my Android app, I managed to connect to the server and receive messages. So, I would say it is working properly right now. The thing is it works exactly the same if I remove the following code:

```
        try {
            signalRFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So I am not sure what signalRFuture.get() does, and if it is completely necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @manuel, we seem to be experiencing the same thing. Did you ever determine if it's necessary?